# GKE Load Balancer Connection Refusing

Tags: docker, gpu, google-kubernetes-engine, gcp-load-balancer

I'm currently in the process of setting up my GPU based app on Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) and configuring an internal load balancer for public access. I have successfully deployed the cluster and load balancer service without encountering any errors. However, when I attempt to access the external IP address of the load balancer, I receive a 'Connection Refused' error. I'm unsure about the cause of this issue and how to effectively debug it.

I applied my deployment YAML file by running the command `kubectl apply -f app-deployment.yaml`. Then, I proceeded to apply my load balancer service YAML file using the command `kubectl apply -f app-service.yaml`. Once both configurations were set up, I used `kubectl get svc` to obtain the External IP Address assigned to the Load Balancer.

Here is my **app-deployment.yaml file**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app-deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app-deployment
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        cloud.google.com/gke-accelerator: "nvidia-tesla-t4"
        cloud.google.com/gke-spot: "true"
      containers:
      - name: sd
        image: $IMAGE
         ports:
            - containerPort: 7860
        env:
        - name: LD_LIBRARY_PATH
          value: /usr/local/nvidia/lib64
        resources:
          limits:
            nvidia.com/gpu: 1
          requests:
            cpu: "3500m"
            memory: "14Gi"
            ephemeral-storage: 10Gi
```

**app-service.yaml file**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: app-deployment
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 7860
```

I have developed an GPU-based application, and I deployed it using a single container. However, when I try to access the 'External-IP' of the load balancer service, the application doesn't run. I would appreciate it if you could help me identify any missing components or configurations that may be causing this issue. Thank you."

Let me know if there's anything else I can assist you with!

Answer (score 0):

Things to troubleshoot:

1. Ensuring the application actually works without a load balancer. You can use `kubectl port-forward pod-name 7860:7860` and then ensure it works with http://localhost:7860
2. Test using the cluster IP instead of external IP address. Lookup the Cluster IP of the svc, spin up a pod in the cluster and run curl http://$CLUSTER_IP
   if this works then that means possibly some firewall or network policy is causing traffic refused.
3. Test using the external IP address from one of the pods inside GCP

Please also provide the output of `curl -v` of all the things you're troubleshooting.